# redirect causes redirect loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Why does this redirect code fails with a `"webpage has a redirect loop"`
browser error message.?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(24\.57|25\.0) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(49\.(4|51|52|64|112|120|128|140|152|208|210|220|232|239)|54\.222) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(91\.234|134\.196|159\.226|161\.207|162\.105|166\.111|167\.139) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(168\.160|192\.(124|188)|193\.0) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/folder/redirect.html [L,NC,R]
```

the purpose is to wildcard the ip ranges and redirect those ranges to 
`http://www.website.com/folder/redirect.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(24\.57|25\.0) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(49\.(4|51|52|64|112|120|128|140|152|208|210|220|232|239)|54\.222) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(91\.234|134\.196|159\.226|161\.207|162\.105|166\.111|167\.139) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(168\.160|192\.(124|188)|193\.0) 
RewriteRule !^folder/redirect\.html http://www.website.com/folder/redirect.html [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: does not work, still says  Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete and chrome says This webpage has a redirect loop note i am using my own ip range as a test when i see the errors.

Comment: Can you try adding: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/redirect\.html [NC] line as the fist condition and test in a new browser.

Comment: ok sorry, your code does work ok, i am using many different ones from you and i noticed i had the wrong name for `folder` in your answer, i changed it and the code works good thanks.